# how to convert list of indices into x , y coordinates in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have list of indices obtained from convex Hull() in open CV i want x and y coordinates of that indices .i have already try with return value true but I cannot use Convexity Defects() further. so is there any way to get coordinates as well as use convexity defect() in open CV.
I want on x and y coordinates of the indices.
here my code is,

```
`hull = cv2.convexHull(c, clockwise=True, returnPoints=False)
 #print(hull)

hull1 = []
for i in hull:
    if len(hull1) == 0:
        hull1.append(i)
    else:
        last = hull1[-1]
        diff = c[i] - c[last]
        if cv2.norm(diff) > 20:
            hull1.append(i)

hull1 = np.asarray(hull1)
hull2 = hull1[:-1].copy()
#print(hull2)

#print(outer_points)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(c, hull2)
#print(defects)
find = []
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
    far = tuple(c[f][0])
    cv2.circle(img1, far, 5, [0, 0, 255], -1)`
```

Comment: What does `returnPoints=False` mean in your call to `cv2.convexHull`?

Comment: it means it will not return coordinate else it will return indices.and convexity defect function only runs when return points= False

Comment: So that means that `hull` is a list of indices into `c`, right?

Answer (score 0):

believing you have already found the contours of the image you are operating on; what you can now do is use the start point of the convexity defect and create an array that hold the specific x coordinate for the defect start point

what I mean is that:

```
_,contour,_ = cv2.findcontour()
#contour is a list holding (x,y) coordinate
con_hull = cv2.convexhull()
con_defect = cv2.convexitydefects(con_hull, contour)
```

since convexity defect is (start_pt, end_pt, farthest_pt, depth) we find all the start points:

```
start = con_defect[:,0][:,0]
x_coord = np.array(contours[s][:,0][:,0]
y_coord = np.array(contours[s][:,0][:,1])
```